# How do I fix runtime error in this division variable?

Tags: c, while-loop, runtime-error

I have a small code here and it works by summing all of 5 digits integers.
for example:
12345 -> 15

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {

    int n,input,total,digitDivisor,division;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    total = 0;
    digitDivisor=10000;
    input=n;

while(input>0){
    division = input/digitDivisor;
    total+=division;
    input-=(input - (division * digitDivisor));
    digitDivisor/=10;
}

printf("%d",total);
return 0;


}
```

I tried to run this code and it resulted "runtime error".

```
  Reading symbols from Solution...done.
  [New LWP 65802]
  [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
  Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
  Core was generated by `./Solution'.
  Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
  #0  0x0000000000401083 in main () at Solution.c:16
  16            division = input/digitDivisor;
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code only deals with numbers up to 5 digits. And you fail to take measures if `digitDivisor` becomes 0 in your loop.

Comment: For separating digits in a number, you normally start from the least significant digit (`input%10`) and then divide `input/=10` as long as `input!=0`

Comment: Exactly: by using the right algorithm, which also doesn't depend on any assumption about the size of the number.

Comment: `input-=(input - (division * digitDivisor));`, replace `-=` with `=`

Comment: `Arithmetic exception` at line `division = input/digitDivisor;` : didn't this ring a bell?

Comment: The problem is clearly a divide-by-zero exception, so the loop must be running 5 times, resulting `digitDivisor` to be zero.  You should start by stepping through the program with a debugger.  Also, to make the question easier to answer, please identify the test value that you are entering that results in the failure noted above.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
input-=(input - (division * digitDivisor));
```

does not make a sense.

It seems you mean

```
input -=  division * digitDivisor;
```

But in any case your approach is unsafe and too complicated.

It is simpler and more safer to sum digits starting form the right most digit as for example

```
do{
    total += input % 10;
} while ( input /= 10 );
```

Also pay attention to that the user can enter a negative number. In this case the do-while loop can be rewritten like

.
do{
int digit = input % 10;
if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;
total += digit;
} while ( input /= 10 );

Or instead of the type `int` you could use the type `unsigned int`.